# NestJS + Heroku - Crashes immediately after a successful build without reason

Tags: heroku, nestjs

**Procfile**

```
web: npm run start:prod
```

**Package.json**

```json
"start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/main",
```

**Heroku logs**

```
2022-05-10T09:01:50.583126+00:00 app[web.1]: [Nest] 22  - 05/10/2022, 9:01:50 AM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +42ms
2022-05-10T09:01:50.818469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-10T09:01:50.875464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Everything works fine on local (`heroku local` and `npm run start`), but crashes on Heroku. I've tried these before:

1. Listen on `process.env.PORT || 8080`
2. All environments are set (`heroku run printenv`)
3. Set `0.0.0.0/0` IP on MongoDB Atlas

These are the environments that Heroku adds:

```
MEMORY_AVAILABLE=512
PWD=/app
PORT=42675
NODE_ENV=production
NODE_HOME=/app/.heroku/node
LINES=17
HOME=/app
COLUMNS=150
SHLVL=0
WEB_MEMORY=512
WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
PS1=\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;32m\]$ \[\033[00m\]
PATH=/app/.heroku/node/bin:/app/.heroku/yarn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/bin:/app/node_modules/.bin
DYNO=run.5170
```

I'm not sure, but could it be for minimum hardware specification?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using port 80 for gateway and `http-session-affinity` was not enabled as it's required for Socket.io. Set `process.env.PORT` for both HTTP and gateway.

To enable `http-session-affinity`, run `heroku features:enable http-session-affinity`